# does appium supports the windows desktop app(which is developed in QT) automation

Tags: appium

I'm facing no such element exception, even though I have provided the valid element property i.e. name.

Does Appium supports the windows app which is developed in QT?
 
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        protected const string WindowsApplicationDriverUrl = "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub";
        protected static WindowsDriver Session;
        protected static RemoteWebElement Result;

```
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void setup(TestContext context)
    {
        // Launch the  app
        DesiredCapabilities appCapabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
      appCapabilities.SetCapability("platformName", "Windows");
       appCapabilities.SetCapability("deviceName", "WindowsPC");
        appCapabilities.SetCapability("app", @"C:\****\Plus\abcd.exe");

        Session = new WindowsDriver<WindowsElement>(new Uri("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), appCapabilities);
        Assert.IsNotNull(Session);
        Session.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60));
    }
    [TestMethod]
    public void lsapVerfication()
    {
        Session.FindElementByName("Logs").Click();
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you can, could you please edit your Q and add the relevant snippet of code and the exact error message? Please also checkout http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm trying to automate the windows app(which is developed in QT). with the help of appium (windows app driver) but facing no such element exception

Comment: Format the first lines of your code